# How to increment/Decrement the Alpabetic letters in indexing titles

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Input text with delimit by tab A - Z series (number and text)

Inputfile.csv:

```
16  ASeries titles
49  ASeries titles
102 ASeries titles
167 BSeries titles
198 BSeries titles
    ...........
178 WSeries titles
187 WSeries titles
187 ZSeries titles
```

Output text should be:

```
<A>
16  ASeries titles
49  ASeries titles
102 ASeries titles
</A>

<B>
167 BSeries titles
198 BSeries titles
</B>
...........
<W>
178 WSeries titles
187 WSeries titles
</W>
<Z>
187 ZSeries titles
</Z>
```

The problem is whenever the alphabetic sequence is missing (X and Y) the output is collapsed.

My Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $csvcnt = "";
readString( "Inputfile.csv", \$csvcnt );

my @_alp = qw(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z);

#$csvcnt = $alp."_starts\n".$csvcnt;
for ( 0 .. 25 ) {
   if ( $csvcnt !~ m/\n\d+\t$_alp[$_]/i ) {
      pop @_alp, $_alp[$_];
      next;
   }
   if ( $_ > 0 ) {
      $csvcnt =~ s/\n\d+\t$_alp[$_]/\n<\/$_alp[$_-1]>\n<$_alp[$_]>$&/i;
   }
   elsif ( $_alp[$_] == 'Z' ) {
      $csvcnt =~ s/\n\d+\t$_alp[$_]/\n<$_alp[$_]>\n$&\n<\/$_alp[$_-1]>/i;
   }
}


#---------------->
sub readString    #Readfile in Strings

  #---------------->
{
   my $File   = shift;
   my $string = shift;
   open( FILE1, "<$File" )
     or die "\nFailed Reading File [$File]\n\tReason: $!";
   read( FILE1, $$string, -s $File, 0 );
   close(FILE1);
}
```

It would be appreciate if anybody could help me on this.

Comment: Your code does not compile. There is stuff missing. It's also completely unreadable and looks like it's an entry for an obfuscation contest, which you would have a high chance to win. Please [edit] the question and include a working example that we can copy and run. It's not clear for me where your input goes with the code you provided.

Comment: @simbabque: I have edited my question.

Comment: What are you doing with that `read`?

Comment: This looks like sort of fake XML. That's kinda filthy.

Comment: @Sobrique: I didn't mentioned this is xml file. This is case i received one of the csv file with the list of titles and I need to split with the range of alphabetic orders. Thats all.

Comment: @Sobrique: May be the splitting will be `[A - starts] ..text.. [A - ends]` ... `[Z - Starts] ..text... [Z - ends]`; There is no mandatory for tagging itself. I need to split the document by alphabetic order.

Comment: No, you didn't, that's true. But the `<A></A>` tag style is specific to XML (or HTML) and that's a documented format. Someone who comes along later might expect that, and be rather annoyed when they find it isn't. JSON or YAML output might also be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out what your code is doing. I can see some real pieces of nastiness in there though, so I'm not going to directly replicate your code, but rather make a best guess at a sane output. Like for example - you appear to be creating something that looks a bit like XML, but that actually isn't. That's pretty nasty.

So instead, here's how you make some XML that looks rather like your target:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
my %entry_for; 

#open your input file
open ( my $input, '<', 'Inputfile.csv' ) or die $!;
#iterate line by line
while ( <$input> ) {
   #match the letter for the 'Series'. 
   my ( $letter ) = m/([A-Z])Series/;  
   #insert it into a hash.   
   push ( @{$entry_for{$letter}}, $_ ); 
}

#create a new XML document
my $XML = XML::Twig -> new; 
#set the root element up. 
$XML -> set_root ( XML::Twig::Elt -> new ('root'));

#iterate the letters we found in the file (e.g. skipping over the missing 'X')

foreach my $letter ( sort keys %entry_for ) { 
   #insert a new XML element for this letter. 
   my $element_for_letter = $XML -> root -> insert_new_elt ('last_child', $letter);
   my $text = join "", "\n", @{$entry_for{$letter}};
   $element_for_letter -> set_text($text);
}

$XML -> set_pretty_print('indented');
$XML -> print;
```

Output for your input data:

```
<root>
  <A>
16  ASeries titles
49  ASeries titles
102 ASeries titles
</A>
  <B>
167 BSeries titles
198 BSeries titles
</B>
  <W>
178 WSeries titles
187 WSeries titles
</W>
  <Z>
187 ZSeries titles
</Z>
</root>
```

But with the added advantage of being actual XML. I'd probably suggest though, you don't want multiple 'fields' inlined into your XML, and rather you'd be better off creating named sub elements or attributes as appropriate. Just because the whole point of a tagged structure like this is to make it more easily parsable.

Specifically problems with your code are:

- You turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings` but then your code doesn't actually compile. "Useless use of array element in void context at line 12." That's because `pop` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.
- `open` should be 3 argument with lexical file handles - so `open ( my $file, '<', 'Inputfile.csv') or die;
- `read` is a piece of nastiness the way you're using it, by passing a scalar-ref and then trying to insert the data into it, based on reading the file size in bytes. Far too complicated, when you can `my $csvcnt = do { local $/; <$input> };` which does exactly the same thing.
- I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with that regex transformation, but it's pretty overkill for what you're actually trying to do. And it's extremely difficult to read.
- Trying to create something that looks like XML, but that isn't actually XML is a pretty nasty thing to do. If you're going to use a defined data transfer format, then you really should stick to the spec. (You need a root node for starters)

Comment: Awesome champs. Master of `XML::Twig`.